# Can I cast Haste on myself?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, targeting

Can my character cast the spell Haste on himself or can it only be cast on another character?

Comment: Related: "[Can a character use Healing Word on themselves?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/51859)", "[Can a character cast Bless on themselves?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/99615)", and "[Can I only touch other creatures with spells such as Invisibility?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/89570)"

Answer (score 28):

### Yes, you can

The spell merely requires a willing creature you can see within range.

And, as per the [rules of spellcasting](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/spellcasting#CastingaSpell), you are indeed a willing creature. So unless the spell specifically states a creature other than yourself, then you can cast Haste (*etc*) on yourself.

> **Targeting Yourself**
>
> If a spell targets a creature of your choice, you can choose yourself,
>   unless the creature must be hostile or specifically a creature other
>   than you. If you are in the area of effect of a spell you cast, you
>   can target yourself.